# How to choose pass value to one parameter to a MATLAB function with multiple inputs?

Tags: matlab, function, input-parameters

`function [c,tc]=v_melcepst(s,fs,w,nc,p,n,inc,fl,fh)`

This function has multiple input parameters, but I only want to specify the value for the `nc` parameter.

In Python, I can easily just do something like `v_melcepst(nc=13)`, but I cannot find the equivalent for MATLAB.

Is this not possible in MATLAB? Do I have to pass default values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed not possible in MATLAB. The arguments are sequential, identified by their location in the argument list.

If  you wrote the `v_melcepst` function yourself, you can rewrite it to accept "name/value pairs", the standard way in MATLAB to do named arguments. In this system, groups of two arguments together work as a single named argument. You would call the function as

```
 [c,tc] = v_melcepst('nc',nc);
```

You can implement this using the old [`inputParser`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.html) class (introduced in R2007a), or with the new [function arguments block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-argument-validation-1.html) (new in R2019b).

Answer (score 3):

Check the documentation on [`varargin`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) and [`nargin`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html).

Basically, do something like

```matlab
function out = my_func(a,varargin)

if nargin == 1
    b = 2; % Your default value
elseif nargin == 2
    b = varargin{1};
end
```

Note that the above does mean you have to have a fixed order of input arguments. Any arguments explicitly named in the function declaration, `a` in this case, always have to be present, and anything within the `varargin` has to be in the set order, e.g. you can add a `c = varargin{2}`, then you cannot set `c` without setting `b`.

If you want to be able to give Python-like input argument, i.e. regardless of the order, you need name-value pairs. This is done via `inputParser`, as suggested in [Cris Luengo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64575411/5211833)